# Call to a member function query() on a non-object Error how to fix?

Tags: php, mysql, class, function

I try every thing but its not working, please some one check this code?

This is Database.class.php file..

```
class Database
{
public $db = NULL;
public $libraries = NULL;

public function Database( $config )
{
    $this->Connect( $config['host'], $config['user'], $config['pass'], $config['database'] );
}
public function Connect($host, $user, $pass, $db)
{
    $this->db = new mysqli( $host, $user, $pass, $db );
}

public function query( $sql )
{
    $f = func_get_args( );
    $i = 1;
    while ( $i <= count( $f ) )
    {
        $args[] = addslashes( $f[$i] );
        ++$i;
    }
    $query = $this->createQuery( $sql, $args );
    if ( !( $result = $this->db->query( $query ) ) )
    {
        exit( mysqli_error( $this->db ) );
    }
    return $result;
}

public function fetch_assoc( $result )
{
    return $result->fetch_assoc( );
}

public function createQuery( $sql, $args )
{
    $i = 0;
    while ( $i != count( $args ) )
    {
        $sql = preg_replace( "/%s/", str_replace( "s", "\\s", $args[$i] ), $sql, 1 );
        ++$i;
    }
    return $sql;
}
}
```

And this is Template.class.php file..

```
public function getPageInfo( $page )
{
$result = $this->Database->query( "select * from `content` where `name` = '%s'", $page );
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc( );
    if ( $result->num_rows == 0 )
    {
        return false;
    }
    return $row;
}
```

Libraries included in index.php PHP..
First Database.class.php
2nd Template.class.php

And also i attached the both files..

http://www.mediafire.com/?xuak9ub7lehkbun

Comment: It does not appear that you are invoking the function that creates the db instance in `$this->db`

Answer (score 1):

Charles Sprayberry is completely right. The code you posted here are either incomplete or you really forget to create a instance of your database class. The first thing missing in this code is the point where you defined your class. Something like `class myDataBase {}` is missing. Well at least I hope you wanted to create one because you are using `$this->`. The second thing is that you used `$this->db` in your `Connect()` function, but are trying to use `$this->Database` in your `getPageInfo()` function. Please provide some more info about the class, where the function `getPageInfo()` resides and how you made the instance of you class.

Comment: i just upload both files, please check.

Comment: Muhammad... To help you we absolutely need the complete class of your Template.class.php file (or at least the important constructors and functions). Without them any help is impossible. You have to understand that you made some dependecies by working with your database object in your template class and it is important to see how you made the instances of your classes.

Comment: i already upload file in this link http://www.mediafire.com/?xuak9ub7lehkbun please download and check.